# Convert uint256 to String[x] in vyper?

Tags: vyper

The [documentation contains, as one of the Data Manipulation built in functions](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/built-in-functions.html?highlight=%22return%20concat%22#data-manipulation), the function `concat()`; the example given is

```
@external
@view
def foo(a: String[5], b: String[5], c: String[5]) -> String[100]
    return concat(a, " ", b, " ", c, "!")
```

How would I go about replacing (for example) `b` with the `String[5]` representation of  a `uint256` variable with a value of (for example) `100`?